# Is it necessary to purge the entire brake circuit if only the front wheels flexible are changed?

Tags: brakes, brake-fluid

The vehicle does not have ABS.

It is the typical X configuration.

Comment: By "flexible" do you mean "flexible brake hose"?

Comment: Yes, the hose that connect the calliper with the rest of the circuit.

Comment: as long as you kept fluid in the reservoir while swapping hoses you should be fine just bleeding the one caliper

Comment: @user4546 Do you know what the syntomps of bad purge are? I assume that at low speed they can't easily diagnosed because the discs did not get so hot.

Comment: the brake pedal will feel soft or spongy.

Comment: Air in the line would be felt immediately, regardless of temperature.

Answer (score 1):

Most people don't do the whole system, but as someone else said the brakes will most likely be spongy and get more so as time goes on.

The other thing you have to remember is that even a tiny amount of air will start to breakdown your fluid

And most people never change their brake fluid.

So it's the start of the system getting slowly worse

It's your call, but in the long term it will bite you

Comment: I already change the brake fluid about four months ago. I'm the third owner. The owner before me have the car from 2002 and never change it. When he told me I can't believe it.

Comment: You are one of the few, that's awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you break the brake system open, you need to **bleed the entire system**. This ensures no air is in the system, nor any contamination. Besides, brakes don't usually get bled enough anyway. Brake fluid should be completely changed every 2 years at a maximum (even I am a failure at keeping up to standard on this). It realistically doesn't take a lot of time/effort to change out the brake fluid, so the optimal solution is to change it all out while you're at it. We are talking about a vital safety system, so why skimp.

Comment: if the reservoir is full and you only open the system at one wheel (hose/caliper) then gravity should help keep air out of the rest of the system (by letting fluid run to the open line). while i agree its definitely ideal to flush/bleed the entire system, i wouldn't say its something that "needs" to be done in every situation

Comment: I already change the brake fluid about four months ago. I'm the third owner. The owner before me have the car from 2002 and never change it. When he told me I can't believe it.

Comment: @E_Blue - Like I said, it's only time, effort, and a bit of brake fluid.